# Proof that a group of order 8888 is solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I need to prove that every group of order $8888$ is solvable by proving that $G^{(3)}=\{e\}$. Can you give some help?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should display some efforts of your own. Let me nevertheless give some hints / one way to do this. $8888=2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 101$. If $P \in Syl_{101}(G)$, prove that $P \lhd G$, since all divisors of $88$ greater than $1$ are smaller than $101$. Look at $G/P$, and show that its Sylow $11$-subgroup is normal (also by inspecting the $\gt 1$ divisors of $8$). If $Q \in Syl_{11}(G)$, this amounts to $PQ \lhd G$. Now use that $PQ$ is cyclic of order $1111$ (and index $8$) and that any group of order $8$ has a trivial second derived subgroup.

Comment: can you explain please why $P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$? I've tried to use the third theorem of Sylow to prove that, but I can't find a version of which the order of $G$ exists: $G = p^3 \cdot q \cdot r$, then we could, somehow, conclude that theres's only r-sylow subgroup

Comment: The number of Sylow $101$-subgroups equals $|G:N_G(P)|$, where $P \in Syl_{101}(G)$. Since $P \subseteq N_G(P)$, $|G:N_G(P)|$ divides $2^3 \cdot 11$, hence this index $\in \{1,2,4,8,11,22,44,88\}$. But also $|G:N_G(P)| \equiv 1$ mod $101$. So $|G:N_G(P)|=1$, that is, $P \lhd G$.